# Looking for a easy way to buildt a scrollbar with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

I am looking for a basic and simple way to buildt a scrollbar with jquery, but i cant seem to find any good tutorials, and i dont want to use a plugin. I have looked at some plugins but my JS skills are way to poor to understand these plugins.

So I am looking for a simple, basic and lightweight to buildt scrollbar, anybody an idea?

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: So? I would say read the about page ;) "Stack Overflow is a programming Q & A site that’s free. Free to ask questions, free to answer questions, free to read, free to index, built with plain old HTML" :P

Comment: Is there a reason you're averse to using a plugin for this? Unless you're just wanting to learn, the goal should be to solve problems with the least amount of hand-rolled code as possible. Hand-rolling your own scrollbar is probably a bit ambitious if your JavaScript skills are poor, by your own admission.

Comment: Yes ofcourse, everything that i buildt is to learn, as at a certain point i dont want to use stackoverflow anymore for my questions ;) No my JS skill arn't that poor, but it takes some time if i dont know where to start, therefor the question for a tutorial, so that i know whats what. Slicing a plugin isn't the best way in my opion to learn.

Comment: @user759235 after you read the [jQuery Plugin Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) you'll see how **easily** actually you can turn anything - into a plugin. Happy coding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like this?

But it's just a non-plugin concept that uses the jQuery UI library:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2TN9g/)

```
var parH = $('.parent').outerHeight(true);
var areaH = $('.scrollable').outerHeight(true);
var scrH = parH / (areaH/parH);

function dragging(){     
    var scrPos = $('.scrollbar').position().top;   
    $('.scrollable').css({top: -(scrPos*(areaH/parH)-1)});
}
    
$('.scrollbar').height(scrH);
$('.scrollbar').draggable({
    axis: 'y',
    containment: 'parent',    
    drag: function() {
         dragging();
    }   
});
```

HTML e.g:

```
<div class="parent">    
    <div class="scrollbar"></div>    
    <div class="scrollable">
        text...
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS e.g:

```
.parent{
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    width:180px;
    background:#eee;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-right:17px;
}
.scrollable{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;        
    width:180px;
    background:#cf5;
}
.scrollbar{
    cursor:n-resize;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    z-index:2;
    background:#444;
    width:17px;
    border-radius:8px;
}
```

You can play to turn it into a plugin and improve the code.

A good start I think.

Comment: Ah, why thank you, this is what i am looking for, simple and clean, as i already do use the UI lib. Many thanks!!

Comment: @user759235 :) you're welcome! Glad you like it. But it still need some improvements as I had no time to play.

Comment: No problem, i just need the basics, i dont have to be spoild ;)